# GetPrivateProfileStringA() cutting off my config value number

Tags: c++, config

I am calling the method [GetPrivateProfileStringA()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to read values from a config.ini file, but when one of my values is over 3 digits, it cuts the value down to 3 (1234 would become 123).

I have a config.ini file which looks like this:

```
[PASSPORT]
MinWidth=200
MinHeight=300

[FEATURES]
MinEyeDistance=20
MaxEyeDistance=1000
...
```

I am reading this config.ini file using the following code:

```
char iniFilename[] = "C:\\config.ini";
char *iniVal = new char[256];

//check config.ini exists
if (std::ifstream(iniFilename))
{
    GetPrivateProfileStringA("PASSPORT", "MinWidth", "200", iniVal, sizeof(iniVal), iniFilename);
    configParam->minImageWidth = atol(iniVal);
    GetPrivateProfileStringA("PASSPORT", "MinHeight", "300", iniVal, sizeof(iniVal), iniFilename);
    configParam->minImageHeight = atol(iniVal);

    GetPrivateProfileStringA("FEATURES", "MinEyeDistance", "10", iniVal, sizeof(iniVal), iniFilename);
    configParam->minEyeDist = atol(iniVal);
    GetPrivateProfileStringA("FEATURES", "MaxEyeDistance", "1000", iniVal, sizeof(iniVal), iniFilename);
    configParam->maxEyeDist = atol(iniVal);
}
```

The buffer string itself (iniVal) gets 3 digits only, so I don't believe it has anything to do with converting the value to a long.

This is my configParam struct:

```
typedef struct _CONFIG_PARAMS
{
    long minImageWidth;
    long minImageHeight;
    long minEyeDist;
    long maxEyeDist;
} STRUCT_CONFIG_PARAMS;
```

I'm kind of lost as to why this is happening. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a really bad way to read ini files. That API has long since been deprecated. Please stop using it. Use a pure C++ ini file parser. There are many. A web search will reveal them. Also, `atol` is a terrible choice for string to integer conversion. Are you sure you are coding in C++? It looks as though you might be still coding in pre standardisation C.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, thanks for your reply! I will find an ini parser and replace this code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - regarding your comment about atol being a terrible choice for string to int conversion, what would be a better way of doing so? Why is it bad? Sorry, just curious.

Comment: It's bad because it doesn't offer any good error detection mechanism. In C++-11 you might use [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which throws exceptions in case of failure. For older C++ you might use stringstream.

Comment: Yeah I just did a bit of a search and found atol to be bad for error detection. I can't use C++-11, so I'll change to stringstream (that's hard to say, hah). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using sizeof() for iniVal, which will return the size of pointer to char, not the size of  the dynamically allocated array. Since this is 4 on your platform it leads to a truncation to 3 chars and a '\0'.

Either allocate iniVal on the stack using

```
char iniVal[256];
```

or use a constant to allocate the array and then pass this to GetPrivateProfileStringA() as in

```
const size_t ArraySize = 256;
char *iniVal = new char[ArraySize];
...
GetPrivateProfileStringA("PASSPORT", "MinWidth", "200", iniVal, ArraySize , iniFilename);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick! I replaced iniVal on the stack instead, solved the issue. Anywho, I think I'll go with @DavidHeffernan's suggestion of using an ini parser.